# Map multiple multisite blogs to the same domain in different paths

Tags: wordpress, url, domain-mapping

I already managed to map a blog from the multiste to a path and it works: e.g. `http://domainmapped.com/path1/`

Until here all good, but when I map  `http://domainmapped.com/` to another blog in the same multisite it works perfectly but breaks the first mapping I did (`http://domainmapped.com/path1/`) now when I try to go to /path1 it shows a 404 error from the `http://domainmapped.com/` blog.

I wonder if theres a better way to do this, the domain is already pointing to the multisite installation and works very well when i map it to the blogs with paths, the issue is when I map the top level domain because it breaks paths.